# Leopard: Extend last partition to fill first partition space on external HD

Tags: partitioning, osx-leopard

I have a 1Tb external HD with 2 partitions. I remove the first one to extend the second to fill the entire disk, but find that I can only extend to the end of the disk, and the unused space is in the begining. Do I have to erase the whole disk and repartition it? - It's not a master partition, just Data, formated as MacOS extended.

Answer (score 1):

What you've discovered is true -- Mac OS X's support for HFS+ volume resizing allows the *end* of the volume to be extended, but it doesn't allow you to move the *beginning* of the partition.

If the free space that used to hold the first partition is big enough to store the contents of the second partition, then I suppose you could save yourself a reformat by creating a new HFS+ partition in the now-free space at the beginning, then copying all your data over there, then deleting your second partition and resizing the first to fill its space.